is it possible to use facebook.js adapter in cloud code to validate authdata?
I am integrating Sign in with Facebook. i am writing a cloud function to link the user.
i want to verify authdata/acess token before using linkWith. i have found posts that suggest below code but this checks only access token and not whether generated from my app.
const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${accessToken}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  if ((data && data.id == authData.id)) {
    logger.info(`verifyFacebookAccessToken() - Facebook user Token verified successfully`)
    return true
  } else {
    throw new Parse.Error(9014, 'Invalid Facebook access token')

  }

facebook.js adapter does this validation so was thinking is it is possible to use like this.
const authenticationLoader = require('../lib/Adapters/Auth'); //how to use correct path here?
async function validateFBAuthData(authData, options) {
  const { adapter, providerOptions } = authenticationLoader.loadAuthAdapter('facebook', options);
  try {
   await adapter.validateAuthData(authData, providerOptions);
  } catch (error) {

    logger.error(`validateFBAuthData() - Facebook user Token verification failed with error ${error}`);
    throw error
  }
}


What do you want to validate the access token if facebook already does that for you?

As I have mentioned above to verify whether the token has really come from my app.
